# can someone explain this Array.prototype.find() polyfill?

Tags: javascript, arrays

on this MDN page [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find]
there is this polyfill:

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(predicate) {
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
      }
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }
      var list = Object(this);
      var length = list.length >>> 0;
      var thisArg = arguments[1];
      var value;

      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i in list) {
          value = list[i];
          if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
            return value;
          }
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

my question is what are these lines for:

```
var list = Object(this);
var length = list.length >>> 0;
```

since `this` is definitely an array (we are augmenting Array.prototype) so why make sure `length` is numerical, and why is Object() used?

Comment: the trouble with this polyfill is that it requires the Object.defineProperty method, which is not available in older browsers that do not implement find.

Comment: As answer indicated; `this` is not guaranteed to be an array, you can see in the following answer what `this` can be (if you need more info than T.J. provided):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 (under `the this variable`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fundamental answer is that the polyfill is just faithfully implementing Step 1 and Step 4 of the algorithm in the ES6 draft spec (§22.1.3.8 as of the May 22 draft).

> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling ToObject passing the **this** value as the argument.
>
> ...
>
> 4. Let *len* be ToLength(*lenValue*).

*(Where ToLength is basically a conversion to a number.)*

And as it's possible to use non-object values for `this` nowadays (via `Function#call` and `Function#apply`, or by just calling the function directly in strict mode), Step 1 makes sense.

> since `this` is definitely an array (we are augmenting `Array.prototype`) so why make sure length is numerical, and why is `Object()` used?

But we **don't** know that `this` is an array. See this note from the current ES6 draft spec:

> The `find` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the `find` function can be applied successfully to an exotic object that is not an Array is implementation-dependent.

You'll find that note on nearly all of the predefined functions assigned to prototypes.

E.g., you can use them for other things, either by assigning them to objects or other prototypes directly:

```
MyNiftyThing.prototype.find = Array.prototype.find;
```

...or via [`Function#call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) or [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3).

So suppose I wanted to use `Array#find` on an `arguments` object. `arguments` is, of course, *array-like* but not an array. So I might do this:

```
function foo() {
    var firstObject = Array.prototype.find.call(arguments, function(val) {
        return typeof val === "object";
    });
    // ...
}
```

A more famous example (not involving `find`) is using [`slice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.13) to convert array-like objects into arrays:

```
function foo() {
    // Turn the `arguments` pseudo-array into a real array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
}
```